# Windows Service: Session Unlock Event with Fast User Switching and Terminal Services Stopped and Disabled

Tags: c#, session, windows-services, unlock, terminal-services

I am writing a C# .NET 3.5 Windows Service that needs to perform some actions whenever a user logon or unlock event occurs. I have tried registering the service by adding my event handler to Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionSwitch:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;

SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += new SessionSwitchEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionSwitch);

void SystemEvents_SessionSwitch(object sender, SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Reason == SessionSwitchReason.SessionLogon)
    { 
        //  Do Task
    }
    else if (e.Reason == SessionSwitchReason.SessionUnlock)
    { 
        //  Do Task
    }
}
```

Also I have tried to override the `OnSessionChange(SessionChangeDescription changeDescription) {...}` method inherited by the `ServiceBase` class:

```
protected override void OnSessionChange(SessionChangeDescription changeDescription)
{
    if (changeDescription.Reason == SessionChangeReason.SessionLogon)
    {
        //  Do Task
    }
    else if (changeDescription.Reason == SessionChangeReason.SessionUnlock)
    {
        //  Do Task
    }

    base.OnSessionChange(changeDescription);
}
```

Many session events are handled by either of the methods described, unfortunately neither of these methods handle the event of a session unlock when fast user switching and terminal services are stopped and disabled. However the event is handled when both services are enabled and running. The work environment this will be deployed on will not have the services enabled.

Is there another way to accomplish this within the C# .NET managed code environment? Many questions I have seen answer the question with the methods described above, they do work correctly but not when both fast user switching and terminal services is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The `CanHandleSessionChangeEvent` property is set to `False` by default.

Insert the following code when initializing the components

```
public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.CanHandleSessionChangeEvent = true;
            this.CanHandlePowerEvent = true;
            this.CanPauseAndContinue = true;
            this.CanShutdown = true;
            this.CanStop = true;
            this.AutoLog = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're having difficulty with `SessionSwitchReason` you can enable 'Other Logon/Logoff Events' in windows eventlog and monitor for these events yourself. It's a bit messy because you have to poll the logs in someway, but it does the trick.

See - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40675839/6715034