# C# SessionSwitchReason.SessionLock NOT triggering when machine is locked via Group Policy

Tags: c#, switch-statement, locking, screensaver, group-policy

**EDIT: The issue here wan't the fact it was locked via GP, it was that it was being run as a service under a service account and it didn't have access to the interactive desktop**

I have a C# application that needs to check for when a user's session is locked, I'm using `Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionSwitch` and this works fine when a user manually locks the machine.

The problem is that when the machine is locked via a group policy (User Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > Personalization > Screen saver timeout) the application doesn't pick up the switch.

Is there another way to check for a machine being locked? Or is there another way to lock machines via group policy that will be picked up by the application?

N.B. The application is running on windows 7 as a service with full admin rights

Here's my code, Thanks in advance!!! :)

```
     public void OnStart(string[] args)
            {

            Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += new Microsoft.Win32.SessionSwitchEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionSwitch);
            }


    void SystemEvents_SessionSwitch(object sender, Microsoft.Win32.SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
           {

            if (e.Reason == SessionSwitchReason.SessionLock)
                  {
                   //DO STUFF
                  }
           }
```

Comment: Currently looking at a solution that involves enabling Other Logon/Logoff Events in the Windows Event Viewer, which will log the workstation locks and unlocks, and then polling this to find out when a user has locked/unlocked their workstation

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this by enabling 'Other Logon/Logoff Events' in Windows Event Viewer and searching for the lock and unlock events.

```
    //Define strings for searching the eventlog.
    string lockEvent = "4800";
    string unlockEvent = "4801";

     //Define the Eventlog source you want (in this case it's Security)
    string LogSource = @"Security";

    //Add these together to make the full query for Lock and Unlock
    string LockQuery = " *[System/EventID=" + lockEvent + "]";
    string UnlockQuery = "*[System/EventID=" + unlockEvent + "]";


//Return true if there is any locked events found.

    private bool CheckForLock()
    {
        //Create Eventlog Reader and Query
        var elQuery = new EventLogQuery(LogSource, PathType.LogName, LockQuery);
        var elReader = new System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogReader(elQuery);

        //Create a list of Eventlog records and add the found records to this
        List<EventRecord> eventList = new List<EventRecord>();
                for (EventRecord eventInstance = elReader.ReadEvent();
                    null != eventInstance; eventInstance = elReader.ReadEvent())
                {

                   eventlist.add(eventInstance);

                 }

          if(eventList.count > 0)
              {
                  return true;
              }
           else
             { 
                 return false;
             }

        }
```

N.B. This will check all the event log, so you need to put a qualifier on how far into the past you want to bee looking.
If you check for lock/unlock sessions every ten seconds, you only want to deal with an `EventRecord` if it's from the same time period.
You can access the `eventlist.TimeCreated` value to do something like...

```
        if (eventInstance.TimeCreated > DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
        {
            eventList.Add(eventInstance);

        }
```

Is it elegant? No. Does it work? Yes.