# While a user unlocks the windows, the application needs to do some tasks in windows 7

Tags: c#

While a user unlocks the windows, the application needs to do some tasks in windows 7. It is a normal application, not a service.
I have tried following-
[How to get windows unlock event in c# windows application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293286/how-to-get-windows-unlock-event-in-c-sharp-windows-application)

this solution works in windows 10 but not in windows 7. What can be done?

Answer (score -1):

See this, windows locking this events you must unlock this in
`User Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > Personalization > Screen saver timeout`
Or do this:

```
   //Define strings for searching the eventlog.
    string lockEvent = "4800";
    string unlockEvent = "4801";

     //Define the Eventlog source you want (in this case it's Security)
    string LogSource = @"Security";

    //Add these together to make the full query for Lock and Unlock
    string LockQuery = " *[System/EventID=" + lockEvent + "]";
    string UnlockQuery = "*[System/EventID=" + unlockEvent + "]";


//Return true if there is any locked events found.

    private bool CheckForLock()
    {
        //Create Eventlog Reader and Query
        var elQuery = new EventLogQuery(LogSource, PathType.LogName, LockQuery);
        var elReader = new System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogReader(elQuery);

        //Create a list of Eventlog records and add the found records to this
        List<EventRecord> eventList = new List<EventRecord>();
                for (EventRecord eventInstance = elReader.ReadEvent();
                    null != eventInstance; eventInstance = elReader.ReadEvent())
                {

                   eventlist.add(eventInstance);

                 }

          if(eventList.count > 0)
              {
                  return true;
              }
           else
             { 
                 return false;
             }

        }
```

From [C# SessionSwitchReason.SessionLock NOT triggering when machine is locked via Group Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40347174/c-sharp-sessionswitchreason-sessionlock-not-triggering-when-machine-is-locked-vi)